# Leetcode Medium: Rotate a LinkedList

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

Here's what I wrote, (yes, it's not the most optimal answer)
But I get a timeout exception sometimes.

````
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def rotateRight(self, head: ListNode, k: int) -> ListNode:
        if (head != None):
            while (k > 0):
                cur = head
                if (head.next == None):
                    prev = head
                else:
                    while (head.next != None):
                        prev = head
                        head = head.next
                    prev.next = None
                    head.next = cur
                k -= 1
        return head```
````

Answer (score 1):

We can use [Floyd's Tortoise and Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd%27s_Tortoise_and_Hare) algorithm for this question, is a bit more efficient:

```
class Solution:
    def rotateRight(self, head, k):
        if not head:
            return

        if not head.next:
            return head

        curr, length = head, 1
        while curr.next:
            curr = curr.next
            length += 1

        k %= length
        if k == 0:
            return head

        slow = fast = head
        for _ in range(k):
            fast = fast.next
        while fast.next:
            slow, fast = slow.next, fast.next

        temp = slow.next
        slow.next = None
        fast.next = head
        head = temp

        return head
```